# Extend the school timetable example (quarkus guide)

Tags: optaplanner

I want to extend the timetable example of the quarkus guide with the entity student. Each student grades all courses (eg. 1-6, more is better). Each student can visit all courses. I am looking for a student - course - allocation, so that the global sum of grades is maximal.

Can I do this with only 1 `PlanningEntity` or must I have 2?

Is there a trick to add a `PlanningVariable List<Student>` to Lesson?

Answer (score 1):

I 'd argue this is a different planning problem, with a different Solver configuration (so a different @PlanningSolution and @PlanningEntity class) but which can reuse problem fact classes (Room, Timeslot, etc).

In practice, I'd remove the `@PlanningEntity` annotation (and the @PlanningVariable annotations) from the Lesson class, because the lesson to room/timeslot assignments will be part of the input, not part of the planning optimization. I am not sure if you even need room/timeslot information at all.

We don't support lists of planning variable (`@PlanningVariableCollection`) yet and I doubt it would be a good fit here because the order of the students in the list doesn't matter. A set might, but we don't support that either yet. It is being worked on. In any case, there's a much simpler solution:

Create a planning entity `StudentToCourseAssignment` class. Follow the docs chapter 22 domain modeling guide to decide if the planning variable is on the student field *xor* the course field.

Also replace the `TimeTable` class accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. A "Set" would be right, not a "List". 
I think, the course assignment to a timeslot is very important, because a student can not visit sychronous courses. If his best graded courses are parallel, the overall outcome would be less than optimal. There are eg. 20 courses, 5 timeslots, 200 students. The solution should tell us which courses in which timeslots
and which students in the courses. In each timeslot a student can visit one of the parallel courses if he wishes.
The sum of all grades of all visited courses of all students should be maximized.

Comment: Ok. PlanningEntity ist StudentToCourseAssignment with PlanningVariable Course Field.
But where to put the link to timeslot?